# Custom Fields & Relationships user profile

Tags: custom, object

I want to add a custom fields (creator profile) to custom object and auto fill in the created by (user) profile to this fields, how can i get the creator profile information ?

Comment: What is the type of field ? Lookup to User record or just a text field ?

Comment: I have a field createdby is lookup user field , and i create a new text field (Formula)for the profile name , but do not know how to get the profile from the createdby refrence.

Answer (score 0):

In your formula field, simply add this fomula : CreatedBy.Profile.Name